# sorting data in a row to multiple rows and columns

Tags: bash

I have a data file with the XYZ coordinates of multiple atoms in a molecule.
It is in a row separated by "," and every 03 values in the sequence indicate XYZ coordinate of one atom. next three is for the second atom.
I need to have an output containing XYZ coordinates against each atom
this is a one row.

```
-2.13  -2.79 -1.67 -2.18  -2.73  -1.75 -2.28 -2.69 -1.71 -2.19  -2.81  -1.83  -2.09 -2.64  -1.79  -2.13 -2.56 -1.90 -2.24 -2.52  -1.88 -2.12  -2.62  -1.98  -2.04  -2.44  -1.91
```

I tried `awk` command but couldn't have a good output

need to have a file like this

```
-2.13   -2.79   -1.67
-2.18   -2.73   -1.75
-2.28   -2.69   -1.71 
-2.19   -2.81   -1.83
```

Comment: Show what did you try.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
echo '-2.13  -2.79 -1.67 -2.18  -2.73  -1.75 -2.28 -2.69 -1.71 -2.19  -2.81  -1.83  -2.09 -2.64  -1.79  -2.13 -2.56 -1.90 -2.24 -2.52  -1.88 -2.12  -2.62  -1.98  -2.04  -2.44  -1.91' |
sed -E 's/([-\.0-9]+[[:space:]]+){3}/&\n/g'
```

- `s` - substitute
- `/` - separator
- `[-\.0-9]+` - a sequence of at least one character of dot, minus and numbers
- `[[:space:]]+` - a sequence of at least one tab or space
- `([-\.0-9]+[[:space:]]+){3}` - take three such sequences
- `&\n` - substitute such sequences for themselves, but add a newline after it.
- `g` - apply the pattern globally rather then just one time

Comment: I would wait with an answer until the questioner has shown what he has tried so far to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert newlines and use paste from stdin

```
echo '-2.13  -2.79 -1.67 -2.18  -2.73  -1.75 -2.28 -2.69 -1.71 -2.19  -2.81  -1.83  -2.09 -2.64  -1.79  -2.13 -2.56 -1.90 -2.24 -2.52  -1.88 -2.12  -2.62  -1.98  -2.04  -2.44  -1.91' | 
sed -r 's/\s+/\n/g' | paste - - -
```